# Android UI Thread Task Causes App to Freeze

Tags: android

The code below is supposed to, every second, track the user's location, add a marker to the map on the location, and add the location to an arraylist of latlng coordinate sets.

Right now when the Track button is pressed the app simply freezes.

Is it related to the way I'm using the UI Thread?

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return;
    }
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                    if (location == null) return;
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f));
                }
            });
    trackButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                paths.add(new ArrayList<LatLng>());
                tracking = true;
                MapsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    public void run() {
                        final ArrayList currpath = paths.get(paths.size()-1);
                        PolylineOptions currpathlineoptions = new PolylineOptions();
                        final Polyline currpathline = mMap.addPolyline(currpathlineoptions);
                        while (tracking) {
                            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(MapsActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                                            if (location == null) return;
                                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15f));
                                            currpath.add(latLng);
                                            currpathline.setPoints(currpath);
                                        }
                                    });
                            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                tracking = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically flooding the UI thread with actions in the loop, so no wonder nothing happens. You could probably just post the action with delay of 1000 every time after onSuccess is called, something like:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(theRunnable, 1000);
```